# how to group a set of b-fields together in buefy/vue js?

Tags: html, vue.js, buefy

Iam Looking for something similar to the fieldset tag present in html that allows us to group a set of similar/related fields together in a group box-https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp.

Sample Screen Shot of the grouping-

[image]

Iam using buefy with vue js and so far i could not find anything similar to the fieldset tag in vue js ?Please help on how can i group a set of b-fields/b-inputs together.

Comment: What you show is look more like panels or cards and you can find about them here: https://bulma.io/documentation/components/card/

Comment: Iam Looking for something similar to the fieldset tag present in html that allows us to group a set of similar/related fields together in a group box-https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

Comment: is there anything like that in buefy/vue js?

Comment: `fieldset` is not supported yet. See the issue https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/886 it has some workarounds